# can we loop like ngFor in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to loop a data like `ngFor` in typescript can we do the same. I'll share my code below

```
 <table id="pdfData" *ngFor="let hubxReport of hubxReportList; let i=index">
    <tr>
      <th>{{hubxReport.categoryName}} + "Test"</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>{{column}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of hubxReport.hubxDataItems">
      <td></td>
      <td>{{item.itemTitle}}</td>
      <td>{{item.itemValue}}</td>
      <td>{{item.itemUnit}}</td>
      <td>{{item.normalRange}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

i want to implement the same way im looping in typescript

Comment: Angular is written in TypeScript... so...?

Comment: Yes, you can but I don't know why do you want to do this :). You need to create a `for` loop and append some element tags to your html

Comment: TS is JavaScript (in the end) use the foreach from js to above your goal. Extra to: you have invalid html structure for your table, you need as many th as td elements.

Comment: i need to do this loop in typescript(angular) not in html section

Comment: Why?? when you are using angular `ngFor` is the easiest way to do that

Comment: yes but i needed the code in typescripy (.ts file) not in html section

Comment: OK, I will create a sample for you

Comment: @KingCk Why would you do this in TS and not in HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion `ngFor` is the easiet way to do that. Anyway Op wants to to do it in typescript. You need to go through the `hubxReportList` and create a table and append some `tr` and `td`. Then append the `table` into your body by `Renderer2`.

Here is a sample that I created:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  hubxReportList = [
    {categoryName: 'nameheader', categoryvalue:'valueheader' , hubxDataItems:  [{itemTitle: 'title',  itemValue: 'value'}]},
    {categoryName: 'nameheader1', categoryvalue:'valueheader1', hubxDataItems: [{itemTitle: 'title1', itemValue: 'value1'}]},
    {categoryName: 'nameheader2', categoryvalue:'valueheader2', hubxDataItems: [{itemTitle: 'title2', itemValue: 'value2'}]},
    {categoryName: 'nameheader3', categoryvalue:'valueheader3', hubxDataItems: [{itemTitle: 'title3', itemValue: 'value3'}]},
  ]

  @ViewChild('div') div: ElementRef;
  
  constructor (private renderer: Renderer2){

  }
  addElement() {
    this.hubxReportList.forEach(t=> {
      const table: HTMLTableElement = this.renderer.createElement('table');
      table.createTHead();
      var hrow = table.tHead.insertRow(0);
      var cell = hrow.insertCell(0);
      cell.innerHTML = t.categoryName;
      cell = hrow.insertCell(1);
      cell.innerHTML = t.categoryvalue;

      var tbody =  table.createTBody();
      t.hubxDataItems.forEach(sub =>{
        var row = table.tBodies[0].insertRow(0);
        var c = row.insertCell(0);
        c.innerHTML = sub.itemTitle;
        c = row.insertCell(1);
        c.innerHTML = sub.itemValue;
      })

      this.renderer.appendChild(this.div.nativeElement, table)
    })
  }
```

[image]

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-append-to-element-bgmc7q?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

Comment: can you help me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74077495/can-we-loop-the-autotable-body-and-header-to-print-multiple-data-dynamically-acc